# how to load image path from image gallery?

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, sencha-touch

I am using sencha-touch and phonegap in android 2.2, I want to load an image, specified by an image path from the image gallery in android. The loaded image path must be saved in an image folder, the image folder must be saved in sqlite like image/1.jpg. Then I want to load the added image path from sqlite. How can I achieve that?

Comment: essentially u want to open gallery then select image then save its path in sqlite?